# Поиск в массиве одинаковых записей

Tags: массивы, php

В цикле формируется массив вида:

```
$d['name'][] = 'вася';
$d['surname'][] = 'васечкин';
$d['id'][] = '1';
```

Нужно найти повторяющиеся id, и вывести всё это в виде строки:

```
вася васечкин - число совпадений: n
```

Где n - кол-во совпадений.
Я применил `array_count_values` для `$d['id']`, но как результаты связать с остальными частями массива?

Comment: а вы массив из результата запрсо к Бд грузите? если так тол может запрос зделать под то что вам нада?

Comment: Нет, данные берутся не из БД.

Comment: Т.е. у Вас будет что то типа

    $d = arraay("name"=>array("вася","петя","вася"),"surname"=>array("в","п","в"),"id"=>array(1,2,1))

?

а что если id 1 будет соответствовать surname не "васечкин" т.е. 

    $d = arrya("name"=>array("вася","петя","жулик"),"surname"=>array("в","п","жулик"),"id"=>array(1,2,1))

?



Comment: Да, так может быть. Получим запись: вася в, жулик жулик совпадений 2.
Интересуют только случаи когда совпадений больше 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно извратится как-то так, но я бы на Вашем месте изменил архитектуру хранения данных, чтобы такие задачи было бы более удобно решать.

```
$id_index = array();
$index = 0;
foreach($d['id'] as $id)
{
    if($id_index[$id])
    {
       $id_index[$id]['count']++;
       $id_index[$id]['index'][] = $index;
    }
    else
    {
       $id_index[$id]["count"] = 1;
       $id_index[$id]["index"][] = $index;
    }
    $index ++;
}

    foreach($id_index as $strings)
    {
       $res_str = "";
       foreach($strings["index"] as $str)
       {
           $res_str .= $d["name"][$str]." ".$d["surname"][$str];
       }
       $res_str .= "(".$strings["count"].")";
       echo $res_str;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, решение помогло :)

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что вам следует немного упростить текущую структуру хранения данных. Например, вы можете вместо массивов использовать классы. ООП всегда несет лишь "свет" в программный код. Так, вы могли бы написать класс, который бы хранил в своих полях информацию о каждом пользователе, имел бы соответствующие методы. Так было бы проще вам как сейчас, да и в дальнейшем разбирательстве своего кода =)

---

Если вам это по каким-либо причинам не подходит, то я готов это обсудить.